# c# how to check if query result is empty as opposed to null

Tags: c#, linq, blazor

I am building a Blazor app and am querying the db

```
var abcGetTblOppDetailsResult = await Abc.GetTblOppDetails(new Query() { Filter = $@"i=>i.OpportunityID=={args.OpportunityID}" });
            tblOppDetails = ecosysGetTblOppDetailsResult;
```

I am using the results in `tblOppDetails` to populate a component.

When there is nothinreturned from the query how do i check if `tblOppDetails` is empty?  i've tried `==null` but even if there is no data its not null so i'm stuck.

I've tried checking if teh count = 0 but every methoid i try from the intellisense tells me things like:

```
error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'Count' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?
```

Please can someone help?

thanks

John

Comment: Are you using `.Count` or `.Count()`?

Comment: ?tblOppDetails.Count
error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'Count' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: .Count() gives me a list of information so i guess that's the one to pursue, thanks

Comment: got it .Count()==0 gives me the answer i'm after.  Many thanks for your help

Comment: @Umair, I can't see how to award you the answer, there's nothing on my screen other than flag or upvote.

Comment: I have added an answer as well, glad that worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per error says, the result has a method called `Count()` and you are probably using it as `Count`.

So it will be like below:

```
var hasItems = result.Count() > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error says it all. You are probably doing

```
if (result.Count == 0) {
    ...
}
```

but there is no property `Count` on `result`. Use

```
if (result.Count() == 0) {
    ...
}
```

which calls the Linq extension method `Count()` the error message is referring to.